# How does one unlock the TLS for the Falken in Ace Combat: Assault Horizon Legacy?

Tags: ace-combat-assault-horizon-legacy

Normally in Ace Combat: Assault Horizon Legacy, you unlock new weapons for your planes by playing them and increasing their kill rate. I've gotten the kill rate on the Falken up to 100%, but the TLS hasn't been unlocked yet. So, I figure that there's another special method to unlock it, and I just haven't figured it out yet. No threads or wikis I've visited have granted me the info, aside from the fact that the weapons does indeed exist in the game, according to the [wiki page](http://acecombat.wikia.com/wiki/Tactical_Laser_System).

How is it unlocked?